# Downloading a pdf file using an android native browser fails

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, pdf, browser

I am trying to download a pdf file using an ASP.Net MVC web application however have noticed that it always fails to download both 1) the file and 2) fail to open up the file within the browser.

Note: The link does not point to a URL + filename with a .pdf extension...it directs to a controller/action that should return the pdf.

All the correct content types/MIME types have been setup correctly:

```
pdf: application/PDF

ppt: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

xlsx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

...just not sure why it doesn't work.

Can anyone shed any light on this please.

What I would like to achieve is either viewing the file within the browser or downloading the file to the phone to view.

Note: Seems to work perfectly well on ios mobile safari browser, and all desktop browsers!

Note 2: the actual error message in the notification area in Android is:

< Untitled >
Download unsuccessful.

Comment: What you see in the browser?

Comment: On the Android browser it says download failed retry... in the notification area

Comment: Have you try to do this: 
Settings > Apps > "All" tab > Download Manager

Click "Force Stop", then click "Clear Cache", then click "Clear Data". Try the download again.

Comment: Yes that seems to have no affect